# Using Facebook Open Graph API for Saving Multiple Scores with Unity3D

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-opengraph, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Facebook-Unity SDK in a game. I have different Levels like Candy Crush Saga and i want to save Players best score in every level on Facebook. and also current Level at which a person is playing. I guess i can not achieve this using Score API. I want to use Open Graph by creating Actions, Objects and Stories. But i don't know how to structure my Data in appropriate way.

Data which i have to Store for each player:

1. Current Level of Player (int).
2. Best Score of Player in each Level (int).

So how should i setup my Objects in Open Graph. Any suggestion will be appreciated.